# WCF: Slow Response Times?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wcf, soa

I have built a WPF client app that hooks into a WCF service via HttpBinding. The service uses Entity Framework 6. On startup I am pulling in a view from a SQl Server db:

```
var query = from a in _Context.vwArticles
            select a;

return query.ToList();
```

vwArticles 12590 rows, 21775 kb.

This is probably the biggest view we maintain. The Client app initialisation is very slow. I've run a trace on the Db which show the query completing very quickly as I would expect. I'm getting a long duration on `Audit Logout` (48670)
although from reading around the subject I think it is the process in general taking a long time rather than the logout in isolation.

My endpoints are set up like so:

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

I have built a simple SOA application very similar to this before which runs much faster with the same db albeit returning a smaller result set. Is there anything simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you using http compression? What is the network bandwidth?

Comment: Have you profiled the application? I think it is importat to know what is causing poor performance. Serialization? Network? Data Access?

Comment: GZip compression on a CustomBinding (instead of a basicHttpBinding) helps a lot with network latency.

Comment: Everything is really quick from my dev machine. I've put breakpoints on the  constructor methods & it flies through them. As soon as I test it in a remote client situation (ie off the network through wireless & vpn) it slows right down so I don't think the client side code is the issue. Getting 9mb upload & download over the vpn...

Comment: No compression at the moment no. The service is self hosted in a WinForms app. No IIS

Comment: From watching the trace it looks like the db returns the result set very quickly but then there's a significant lag returning the data back to the client.

Comment: Have you tried what Sharped sugests? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458(v=vs.110).aspx